# Calculate matrix in equation with constraints on values

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let's say I have the matrices

$A = B \cdot C$

The matrices $A$ and $C$ are given, they contain real values $\in[0,1]$. I want to calculate the matrix $B$, which values can only be binary, $\in\{0$, $1$}, so

$B = A \cdot C^{-1}$

is not an option. Additionally I might need to place constraints on rows or columns of $B$, such that the sum of a row/column must be $1$.

I realize that this might not be exactly possible and I don't mind - it is sufficient to reduce the sum of squared error of $A - B \cdot C$ as much as possible. What method or type of method do I did to use to solve this kind of problem.

Regarding the sizes of the matrices:

- $A$ is a $c$ x $o$ matrix
- $B$ in a $c$ x $c$ matrix
- $C$ is a $c$ x $o$ matrix

where $c$ is somewhere between 1 and 100, and $o$ can be very large, let's say between a five hundred and a million or more. Brute force is not efficient as there exist potentially $2^{100\cdot100}$ variants of $B$.

(It is not exactly matrix factorization, is it? Is it some special kind of matrix-decomposition? It looks to me like a problem of solving a system of linear equations, but I am not sure. I feel like I fail to see the obvious.)

Comment: In practice, what I would do is very simple: choose the norm you'd like, and then run a script with all possibile matrices filled with $\{0,1\}$, compute the norm of all $\|A-BC\|$ for all different $B's$ and you'll be done. A computer will handle that in no time. After all you don't have so many possibilities if the dimension is not too large.

Comment: @b00nheT: I updated information about the matrices. I don't think that brute force is an option.

Comment: You  may get an answer by formulating the problem as a Linear Programming problem.

Comment: @NoChance: Thanks for the idea. Seems like I need Integer Linear Programming / Integer Programming?

Comment: Correct, Integer programming may work for your case. The trick is usually in formulating the problem as such.